# Change the font within chemmacros \iupac environment?

Tags: fonts, chemmacros, cfr-lm

I am using `cfr-lm` as the font in my thesis, as I really like the look of the old style numbers in body text, and I have a LOT of numbers in my thesis. I'm also using the `chemmacros`/`chemformula` combination.

However, I find they (or at least typceface's this implementation of them), don't work very well in chemical formulas or names. Now there are two easy fixes for this with `chemformula`, however I can't find an equivalent for `chemmacros` nomenclature module.

It looks like all I'd have to do is add a `\plstyle` to the start of every `\iupac{` command, but I'm not sure how to do that, or if that is possible without breaking other things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\iupac{(1\textit{R},2\textit{R})-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate} Old style

\iupac{\plstyle(1\textit{R},2\textit{R})-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate} Lining

\iupac{2,2':6',2''-terpyridine} Old style

\iupac{\plstyle 2,2':6',2''-terpyridine} Lining


\end{document}
```

Now, I *could* do something like `\newcommand\iupacl[1]{\iupac{\plstyle #1}}` but then I'm going to be forever hunting down instances of `\iupac` and having to change them as I copy in text from older papers, so I'm keeping that as a backup if there isn't an easy way to change the font within the `\iupac` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with v6.1 (2022/02/13) there is the option  `nomenclature/iupac-format`. Also note the use of `\cip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  nomenclature/iupac-format=\plstyle
}
\begin{document}

\iupac{\cip{1R,2R}-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate}

\iupac{2,2':6',2''-terpyridine}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an official interface---you could make a feature request---but something like this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm,color}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\chemmacros_define_keys:nn {nomenclature}
  {
    iupac-format .code:n  = 
      {
         #1
      } ,
  }
\RenewDocumentCommand \iupac {O{iupac-format=\plstyle}m} { \chemmacros_iupac:nn {#1} {#2} }  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\iupac{(1\textit{R},2\textit{R})-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate} Old style

\iupac{\plstyle(1\textit{R},2\textit{R})-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate} Lining

\iupac{2,2':6',2''-terpyridine} Old style

\iupac{\plstyle 2,2':6',2''-terpyridine} Lining

1234567
\end{document}
```

Instead of using the default of the optional argument, you could also put the option before the `#1`, then it would be always executed.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify that last bit? Is it not always being executed now?