# Change the font within chemacros \iupac environment in with fontspec in lualatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, chemmacros, newcomputermodern

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570356) not long ago, and now want to move from `cfr-lm` and `pdflatex` to `newcomputermodern` with `fontenc` and `LuaLaTeX`.

That is, I would like to use old-style numbers, everywhere except inside `chemmacros` `\iupac{}` environment.

I'm not sure how to adapt the code from [the previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570393) but I'm not sure how to move from `\plstyle` which continues on from the current position, to `\liningnums{}` which covers only the text inside the brackets. Alternatively I'm sure `fontspec` has some way of manually adjusting those font features until the end of the environment, but I'm not sure how to do that without changing the whole document's font. (`chemformula` has a built in command for this, but `chemmacros` does not.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures+{Numbers=OldStyle}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\iupac{(1\textit{R},2\textit{R})-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate} Old style

\iupac{\liningnums{(1\textit{R},2\textit{R})-\trans-1,2-Cyclohexanedicarboxylate}} Lining

\iupac{2,2':6',2''-terpyridine} Old style

\iupac{\liningnums{2,2':6',2''-terpyridine}} Lining

1234567890

\liningnums{1234567890}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Following Ulrike's previous answer: `\RenewDocumentCommand \iupac {O{iupac-format=\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyleOff}}m} { \chemmacros_iupac:nn {#1} {#2} }`

Comment: @Marijn Ahhh! I didn't realize \addfontfeature would respect scope like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse the other answer. To switch to a different number style locally, use either `\addfontfeature`, or define a new font family which has the right Number setting. I also suggest to restrict the \defaultfontfeatures command to avoid that you get lots of warnings from the math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily,\sffamily,\ttfamily]{Numbers=OldStyle}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\newfontfamily\ncmliningnums{NewCM10-Book.otf}[
  Numbers=Lining,
  ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic.otf,%
  BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,%
  BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic.otf,%
  SlantedFont=NewCM10-Book.otf,%
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
  BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,%
  BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25}]


\begin{document}

1234567890

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}1234567890}

{\ncmliningnums 1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip about default font features, going through the warnings and working out how to fix them is on the todo list but wayyy down there.